# Keep Watched Variable Tab Open After Debug

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

When I'm debugging in Visual Studio I like to see an object and all its nested properties open in a watch window. How can I persist that watch window so I can view it as a tab after I've ended the debugging session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not see the value of watching of your object if you close debug. What you can do how ever is to use the functions that [`System.Diagnostics`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics(v=vs.110).aspx) library offer to monitor some of your variables.

and by using this code

```
Debug.Write("value of :" + YourVariable);
```

you can then use the [DebugView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/debugview.aspx) from Sysinternals to monitor that debug output.